# How to search html file for css reference without FQDN?

Tags: html, css, bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script that will search inside given HTML file, locate if there are any CSS Style reference without the FQDN and add it in-line.

For example: 
Replace `href="css/style.css"` to `href="http://my.domain/css/style.css"`

(of course the directory is not always "css". can be anything else...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    [root@h2g2w lib]# cat toto
    href=css/style.css
    href=other/style.css
    href=example/style.css
    href=css/style.css
    href=css/style.css
    href=css/style.css
[root@h2g2w lib]# sed  -i "s/href=\(.*\)\/*.css/href=http:\/\/my.domain\/\1/" toto

[root@h2g2w lib]# cat toto
href=http://my.domain/css/style
    href=http://my.domain/other/style
    href=http://my.domain/example/style
    href=http://my.domain/css/style
    href=http://my.domain/css/style
    href=http://my.domain/css/style
[root@h2g2w lib]# 

[root@h2g2w lib]#
```

what you need to isolate the subdirectory name as a sub-pattern on search pattern & repast it over the substitution pattern  (.*) will be pasted as \1 in over the replacement pattern in substitute/pattern/replacement/

in the command :  `sed  -i "s/href=\(.*\)\/*.css/href=http:\/\/my.domain\/\1/"`

substitue href=(copy)/whatever.css by href=http://my.domain/PASTE/end of existing line

now you can adapt to feet your needs

to search lignes wihtout http
preceed you commands by

```
sed  ':v/http/ ......
```

with the pattern you choose.
now you can adapt at your needs

Comment: Thanks!!
This is Great.

Comment: Just another issue -

The following script will add the FQDN even it is already there... and that is a problem :)
Is there a  way to replace the "href=" only if there is not "http" reference? 

Thanks

Comment: as said earlier     to search lignes wihtout http preceed you commands by

sed  ':v/http/ ......       you have to adapt by yourself I haven't your files so I cannot full  fill a script that you can just copy/paste

Comment: I'll just give you an example of everything I need to do:
I have the following code:
----------------------------------
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://my.domain/css/main.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wraper_page.cs " /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Menu.Skin" />

Comment: So I want the script to cover all option all over the document (Ignore the existing http reference | add FQDN for the missing one | take in consider also the ".cs" file)

And also - If I want to use a variable for my FQDN? using $1 for example? 
So I'll run the script as follow:
./myscript.sh http://my.domain


Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ sed -i 's|href=".*/style.css|href="http://my.domain/style.css|g' file.txt


 $ cat file.txt
 href="one/style.css"
 href="css/style.css"
 href="style/style.css"
 href="check/style.css"
 href="two/somethingelse"
```

Result:

```
$ sed 's|href=".*/style.css|href="http://my.domain/style.css|g' file.txt
href="one/style.css"
href="css/style.css"
href="style/style.css"
href="check/style.css"
href="two/somethingelse"
```